# why ckeditor content stored in database do not display as html in php

Tags: html, laravel, ckeditor5

I am working on blog section of a project. I integrated ckeditor and saved data to database. When i display it in php it shows plain text instead of html. I have tried different ways but couldn't resolve the problem. Please some one guide me. thanks.
my function to save data in database

```
  public function store_blog(Request $request){
    $fname=null;
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $file=$request->file('image');
        $fileName=uniqid().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('uploads/blogs/'),$fileName);
        $fname=asset('uploads/blogs/'.$fileName);

    }

    $bbody=$request->blog_body;
    $bbody = trim($bbody);
    $bbody = stripslashes($bbody);
    $bbody = htmlspecialchars($bbody);



    Blog::create([
        "title"=>$request->title,
        "short_description"=>$request->short_desp,
        "body"=>$bbody,
        "cover_image"=>$fname,
        "slug"=>str_replace(" ","_",$request->title),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('blog_index')->with('success','Blog created successfully');
   
}
```

this function saves content successfully. But when i fetch and display in laravel blade view. Ckeditor content displayed all html as plain text/string. How can i force this to render html.

function to fetch blog from database

```
public function show_Ablog(Request $request,$slug){
    $blog=Blog::where('slug',$slug)->first();
   
    
    return view('website.showAblog',compact('blog'));
}
```

in my blade view

```
            <div class="col-lg-12 dat">
            
                {{($blog->body)}}
            </div>
```

i have tried all functions like

```
htmlspecialchars
htmlentities
```

how could i resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with php syntax like

{!! $blog->body !!}

Note: Make sure that your editor sending proper html content?

Comment: Why use `@php` when you can `{!! $blog->body !!}` . Try to avoid @php as much as you can.

Answer (score 3):

When your data contains HTML tags then use

Write your code in blade file like

```
{!! $blog->body !!}
```

Comment: Please mark as verified if its help for you Thank you for UPVOTING !!!...